# Can't get Bluetooth to work on Asus laptop

Tags: bluetooth, asus, bluez

Before I switched my laptop to Ubuntu I had Bluetooth capability; but, now I can't get it to work.

When I open Bluetooth, I get an error telling me bluez daemon is not running. I have followed the instructions on quite a few of the Ask Ubuntu answers and so now I am asking the question myself. I am a new to using the terminal so please make answers user friendly.

Comment: Have you tried starting the bluetooth service? "sudo service bluetooth start"

Comment: I have and nothing happens when i use this command